# R ggplot: Change Grouped Boxplot Median line

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have plotted grouped boxplots and now I would like to replace the standard black median line with a white line while keeping the borders in an other color. I'm following the instructions on the site [Minimalist Boxplots](http://biochemres.com/beautiful-minimalist-boxplots-with-r-and-ggplot2) because I really like their style.

They use the command `stat_summary(geom = "crossbar", width=0.65, fatten=0, color="white", fun.data = function(x){ return(c(y=median(x), ymin=median(x), ymax=median(x))) })`.
That command worked well with simple boxplots:
[image]

But now that I'm trying to use it on my grouped boxplots its not working anymore (white median line is missing):

[image]

Here is my the code for reproducing my data:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  W = sample(1:100),
  M = sample(1:100),
  A = sample(1:100),
  O = sample(1:100),
  Type = sample(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")))
```

And my script:

```
Data_Boxplot <- melt(Data,id.vars='Type', measure.vars=c('W','M','A', 'O'))
Boxplots <- ggplot(Data_Boxplot, aes(Type, value, group=variable)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NULL, aes(color=variable, fill=variable)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "crossbar", width=0.65, fatten=0, color="white", 
               fun.data = function(x){c(y=median(x), ymin=median(x), ymax=median(x))})
Boxplots
```

What do I have to change? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only mapped `x` and `y` for the `geom_boxplot`. Variables that are shared among geoms should be mapped for all. In this case, you also need to group by `variable`.

```
ggplot(Data.m, aes(Type, value, group=variable) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NULL, aes(color=variable, fill=variable)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "crossbar", width=0.65, fatten=0, color="white", 
               fun.data = function(x){c(y=median(x), ymin=median(x), ymax=median(x))})
```

I did not test, as you did not provide data.

### Edit:

Ok, now that we have a good example with data we can see what's going on.

There is actually a two issues I had missed. Both are because `geom_boxplot` will automatically solve some problems for you because of the `fill`, that `stat_summary` doesn't. So we'll have to do them manually.

Firstly, we want to be grouping on both `variable` as well as `Type`, we can do this by using the `interaction` function.

Secondly, the boxplots are automatically dodged (i.e. moved apart within groups), while the horizontal lines aren't. We'll define our positioning using `position_dodge`, and apply it to both geoms. Applying it to both is the easiest way to make them exactly line up. We end up with:

```
p <- position_dodge(0.8)
ggplot(Data_Boxplot, aes(Type, value, group = interaction(variable, Type))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = variable, fill = variable), outlier.colour = NULL, position = p) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "crossbar", width = 0.6, fatten=0, color="white", position = p,
               fun.data = function(x){c(y=median(x), ymin=median(x), ymax=median(x))}) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! The white lines are now shown, but I have the problem that the boxes are not grouped anymore. I included a picture above.

Comment: I can't help you without a reproducible example. See ['how to make a great R reproducible example?'.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: That linked website is really helpful, thank you. I edited my post and included a script to reproduce my data.